# How to remove the [L] Flag for Wordpress index .php mod_rewrite

Tags: redirect, htaccess, seo, mod-rewrite

I have been having difficulties with redirecting query strings for the new WordPress site we launched.

I am using mod_rewrites to do the redirect and I can get them to work by removing the [L] flag from the WordPress index.php mod_rewrite (see below).

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

[Complete .htaccess](http://pastebin.com/3FHSCNgC)

The problem that I am having is that the flag keep getting put back and so need to know how I can change the WordPress .htaccess output while still allowing for updates etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove write access for the PHP user on the system.

Comment: @toscho, I'm curious if there's a reason not to use the `mod_rewrite_rules` filter and do a string replacement to remove the flags.

Comment: @DaveRomsey Too slow, might not work in the future, unnecessary complex solution for a simple problem.